# Doubled answer problem with Python for loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

When I run the following Python code, instead of receiving just one name and average, I'm receiving the information duplicated and always the first average it's not the number intended.

This is my code:

```
students = ["erick", "rafael", "marcel", "junior"]
grades = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]


for index in range(len(grades)):
    summ = 0
    for grade in grades[index]:
        summ += grade
        average = summ / 2
        print(students[index])
        print(average)
```

This is the result:

```
erick
0.5
erick
1.5
rafael
1.5
rafael
3.5
marcel
2.5
marcel
5.5
junior
3.5
junior
7.5
```

Why is this occurring, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You're calculating the average and printing it each time through the inner loop. You should move that to the outer loop.

Comment: No loop needed: `average = sum(grades[index]) / len(grades[index])`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the average once **outside** the inner loop. Also, use the length of the list instead of hardcoding `2`.

```py
summ = 0
for grade in grades[index]:
    summ += grade
average = summ / len(grades[index])
print(students[index])
print(average)
```

A more idiomatic solution would be to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together in order to iterate over them in parallel rather than working with indexes.

```py
for student, grade in zip(students, grades):
    print(student)
    print(sum(grade) / len(grade))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prints are executed twice, because they are inside the second for loop which loops through the grades.

```
students = ["erick", "rafael", "marcel", "junior"]
grades = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]


for index in range(len(grades)):
    summ = 0
    for grade in grades[index]:
        summ += grade
        average = summ / 2
    print(students[index])
    print(average)
```

With proper indentation it works like intended.